# Redux states don't update inside the firebase auth onAuthStateChanged callback

Tags: javascript, firebase, redux, firebase-authentication

I use a redux state inside the firebase auth onAuthStateChanged callback like this

```
...
const authUser  = useSelector(state => state.authUser)
console.log(authUser.status)
useEffect(() => {
  const unsubscribe = onAuthStateChanged(auth, () => {
     console.log(authUser.status)
     if (authUser.status === 'loading') {
       dispatch(updateStatus('loaded'))
  }
  return () => unsubscribe()
}, []);
...
```

First it logged

> loading

> loading

then after I signed in the auth state changed and it logged

> loaded

> loading

The initial state of status is `loading`. Every time the auth state changes it will call the callback function. The value of status inside the callback is always `loading` even that its value in the store has changed to `loaded`. Why doesn't its value in the callback change?

Comment: `status` seems to be a `const` in your code. Are you sure you can change its value somewhere?

Comment: I just editted the question. Even that status isn't a const, it still never changes inside the callback. It stuck there and is treated as a const instead of being referenced from the outside scope.

Comment: the answer is here https://overreacted.io/a-complete-guide-to-useeffect/ for those ones facing the same issue

Comment: Great to hear you found a solution @kr17. Can you post the actual code of how you solved it as a self-answer? That makes it clear to the system that the problem is solved, and increase the chances that others find your solution in the future.

Answer (score 0):

After reading this [explanation from Dan](https://overreacted.io/a-complete-guide-to-useeffect/) I knew that states, props will never change inside a closure. To achieve the logic I wanted, just rewrite the update logic inside createSlice

```
...
    updateStatus: (state, action) => {
      if (state.auth.status === 'loading') {
        state.auth.status = 'loaded'
      }
    }
...
```